# LWC Datatable Multiline Edit with lightning/uiRecordApi question

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps

I'm trying to use multiple inline edits to update values of the datatable, I've looked at the previous answers and created this **accountEditList** property to refresh apex. It doesn't seem to work.

```js
    import {LightningElement, api, track, wire} from 'lwc';
    import getAccountEditList from '@salesforce/apex/AcccountEditController.getAccountEditList';
    import {updateRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';

    export default class Acceditdatatable extends LightningElement {

    @api accountIdList = [];
    @api saveDraftValues = [];
    @api accountEditList = [];
    @track draftValues = [];
    @track updateRows = [];

    @track columns = [
        {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', editable: true},
        {label: 'Website', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', editable: true},
        {label: 'Date', fieldName: 'Acc_Custom_Date__c', type: 'date', editable: true},
        {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Acc_Custom_Email__c', type: 'email', editable: true},
    ];


    @wire(getAccountEditList, {Ids: '$accountIdList'})
    wiredAccount(data, error) {
        this.updateRows = data;
        if (data) {
            this.accountEditList = data;
            console.log('totalaccountsaftersearchwireservice', this.accountEditList);
        }
    }

    handleSave(event) {

        const recordInputs = event.detail.draftValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            return {fields};
        });

        console.log('RECORDINPUTS', recordInputs);

        const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            // Clear all draft values
            this.draftValues = [];
            // Display fresh data in the datatable
            return refreshApex(this.updateRows);
        }).catch(error => {
            // Handle error
        });
    }



Console statement : RECORDINPUTS [{"fields":{"Name":"test1","id":"row-0"}},{"fields":{"Name":"test2","id":"row-1"}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your console statement shows that you are not setting your id field correctly. If you're using lightning-datatable, you need to specify the key field correctly to grab the id values from the edit event.